# Configuration of test directories in a mavenized Android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, maven-3

I have an Android project, which uses Maven. Originally, it worked fine with Eclipse (ADT).

But then I added a unit test and moved the source code from `src` to `src/main/java` directory and put my unit tests into `src/test/java` folder.

Thereafter Eclipse started to complain about wrong package names and refuses to run/debug my unit tests.

I tried to fix the problem by adding `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` to Java source path.

But this didn't help, I still can't run unit tests.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: You wrote tests in the same Adnroid project?

Comment: Yes. AFAIR I created the project using a Maven archetype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that [MoreUnit](http://moreunit.sourceforge.net/#doc-projectproperties) allows to change the location of the unit tests. This solved my problem.