# How to create an eclipse-compatible, mavenised Android project?

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, maven-3, android-maven-plugin

I need to create a Maven project for my Android application. When I use the normal Android Maven plugin, it produces a file structure with incorrect location of test classes (the test classes lie where Maven expects them, but eclipse doesn't and it leads to difficulties debugging unit tests in eclipse). There is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210500/configuration-of-test-directories-in-a-mavenized-android-project) for this, but it isn't very elegant.

How can I create a Maven project, which will be compatible with eclipse (allow me to run unit tests in eclipse and - ideally - deploy my application to an emulator from within eclipse) ?

Comment: I explained this dilemma [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593842/simple-non-api-android-junit-test-in-eclipse-with-android-maven-plugin/15650175#15650175), you probably came cross this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this project](https://github.com/xwiki-contrib/android-client) can serve you as inspiration.

Sonatype, one of the main developers of Maven and related projects, has a [free chapter](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/android-dev.html) about using Maven for Android.